# How to avoid Mongoid (or MongoDB) replacing empty arrays with null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, angularjs, mongodb, mongoid4

Background: I have built an API in Rails and a client in Angular. My API will connect to a third party API and grab some data. This data will come in as an nested object/hash which is stored in MongoDB/Mongoid.

When my Angular clients manipulates the data and send it to my API to save it, all empty arrays within the nested hash/object are replaced with `null`.

Is there a way I could avoid this from happening (other than manually converting all the `null`s back to `array` but that would be tedious and complex as I'd need to push this updated data to the third part API also)?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 field :your_field, type: Array, default: []
```

or

```
 field :your_field, type: Hash, default: {}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware but I mean for a field which is a hash that has nested arrays in it... and remember, the data already exist, I've imported from another API, its just when I updated it, Mongoid replace the empty arrays that's already there and replace it with `null`

Comment: which rails version are you using?, if you are using rails 4 then just try config.action_dispatch.perform_deep_munge = false, you can check this link for more details http://www.amilitalia.it/github.com/rails/rails/pull/13188.html

Comment: that seems to have worked like a charm :) Do you want to modify your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: it's good to hear from you, i dont care about score, i am happy to help you out, that's great!. :-)